# Spring JPA how to delete entry from ModelAndView and from view but leave it in db?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a web application where you can send messages between users. I want to add an option that allows you to remove the message from your view, but not from the db. How to do this?

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MessagesController {

@Autowired
private MessageService messageService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/messages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ModelAndView messages(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam(value = "p",    defaultValue = "1") int p) {

    Message message = new Message();
    Authentication auth =   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    List<Message> inbox = messageService.getInbox(auth.getName());
    List<Message> outbox = messageService.getOutbox(auth.getName());

    modelAndView.setViewName("app.messages");
    modelAndView.getModel().put("message", message);

    modelAndView.getModel().put("inbox", inbox);
    modelAndView.getModel().put("outbox", outbox);

    return modelAndView;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/messages", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ModelAndView messages(ModelAndView modelAndView, Message message) {

    modelAndView.setViewName("app.messages");

    Authentication auth =        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    message.setSender(auth.getName());
    messageService.send(message);
    return modelAndView;

}

}
```

View:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>



<form:form commandName="message">
Receiver:
<form:input path="receiver" type="text" name="receiver"
    class="form-control"></form:input>
Title:
<form:input path="title" type="text" name="title" class="form-control">   </form:input>
Content:
<form:textarea path="content" name="content" rows="5"
    class="form-control"></form:textarea>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="send" />

</form:form>
<br>

<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseInbox">Inbox</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseInbox" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${inbox}" var="qwe">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><c:out value="${qwe.sender}">    </c:out></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><c:out value="${qwe.title}"> </c:out></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><c:out value="${qwe.content}"></c:out></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><c:out value="${qwe.sent}"></c:out></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <div class="panel-footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOutbox">Outbox</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOutbox" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${outbox}" var="qwe">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><c:out value="${qwe.sender}"></c:out></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><c:out value="${qwe.title}"></c:out></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><c:out value="${qwe.content}"></c:out></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><c:out value="${qwe.sent}"></c:out></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <div class="panel-footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest: When your try to delete the message from the "View", just delete it from the table you are currently querying and add it to another table, like "deleted_messages", or "moved_messages". That way, you do not get the message in your View anymore, and you don't loose it.

Comment: This idea is good, but look, i am using same table for receiver and sender , so if I move the message as a receiver it will disappeared for sender as well and vice versa. Looks like I will need to create one table for sender and one for receiver and do it like you say :)
Still waiting for some ideas!

Comment: Well, I implemented a messaging component into my application too, and I came across the exact same problem. And for example. Let's say you have a table called `deleted_conversations`. In that table I've added the conversation_id which gets deleted and also the user that deletes that conversation. So, your main query needs to depend on selections from other tables, like this one. Or something in that direction.

Comment: The main difference from your implementation was that I stored my messages like conversations, so I did not have a inbox and outbox, to me they were all the same. Like in Facebook, you have all in one place.

Comment: Tell me, how do you keep your conversation? Do you create a new table for each converasion?

Comment: No, I have a table `conversations` where I store the conv_id, the sender, the reciever, date when conversation started, and another table `conversation_reply` where each reply is stored. Basically when you create a new conversation, I add one entry to the `conversations` table with the data mentined above, and another entry in the `conversation_reply` table where I store which conv_id it references, the user that sent the message, the message itself, the date, and so on.

Comment: Could you link some source code, for example from github?